# Blending two functions, where one is inverse

Tags: function, math, blending, inverse

Let me first explain the idea. The actual math question is below the screenshots.
For musical purpose I am building a groove algorithm where event positions are translated by a mathematical function F(X). The positions are normalized inside the groove range, so I am basically dealing with values between zero and one (which makes shaping groove curves way easier-the only limitation is x'>=0).
This groove algorithm accepts any event position and also work by filtering static notes from a data-structure like a timeline note-track. For filtering events in a certain range (audio block-size) I need the inverse groove-function to locate the notes in the track and transform them into the groove space. So far so good. It works!

[image]

[image]

In short: I use an inverse function for the fact that it is mirrored to (y=x). So I can plug in a value x and get a y. This y can obviously plugged into the inverse function to get first x again.

Problem: I now want to be able to blend the groove into another, but the usual linear (hint hint) blending code does not behave like I expected it. To make it easier, I first tried to blend to y=x.

```
B(x)=alpha*F(x) + (1-alpha)*x;
iB(x)=alpha*iF(x) + (1-alpha)*x;
```

For alpha=1 we get the full curve. For alpha=0 we get the straight line. But for alpha between 0 and 1 B(x) and iB(x) are not mirrored anymore (close, but not enough), F(x) and iF(x) are still mirrored.

Is there a solution for that (besides quantizing the curve into line segments)? Any subject I should throw an eye on?

Comment: Wait... are you the Andre Michelle who built the tone matrix?  If so, then thanks for making such an awesome app!

Comment: Well, yes and thanks.
I guess the solution is a approximation of the equation with switched x,y. I wish math were more reliable.

Comment: i've added the images inline.  could you explain more without relying on terms like "groove" and "blend" (does that mean interpolate?)?  perhaps by commenting on the images? it sounds like you have two function from [0,1]->[0,1] which you are combining in a linear way, and you want the inverse?

Comment: By _groove_ I mean any function that translates the events.
By _blend_ I mean interpolate from function A to function B.

Comment: Perhaps this flow diagram can clarify a bit. This sequence is important for my implementation: X > F(X) > Do something with F(X) > invF(X) > X, where X is a value between 0 and 1. Now think of having two of these chains [A,B] and I smoothly want to interpolate the results from A to B. It is crucial that any interpolation step between is following the upper rule (still having inverse properties).

Comment: Let's see if I understand correctly: you have two "groove functions" `F(x)` and `G(x)` which both take values between 0 and 1 when `x` is between 0 and 1, and the inverse of these functions are `iF(x)` and `iG(x)`. Now you construct a new function `B(x) = alpha*F(x) + (1-alpha)*G(x)` and you need to find the inverse of that function in terms of `iF(x)` and `iG(x)`? If so, I think you might want to ask this at the [math site](http://math.stackexchange.com), perhaps in parallel with this question here. They can tell you if there is a mathematical procedure that would be useful.

Comment: Okay, I think I was looking for some magic to make the transformation of my equation less horrible. Basically I just need to swap x and y and transform to y again. This is acceptable for an interpolation from simpler equations to y=x. But I was looking for a general approach to blend two more complex equations. Looks like a really hard task.
http://files.andre-michelle.com/temp/simpler.png

Answer (score 1):

you are combining two functions, f(x) and g(x), so that y = a f(x) + (1-a) g(x).  and given some y, a, f and g, you want to find x.  at least, that is what i understand.

i don't see how to do this generally (although i haven't tried very hard - i mean, it would be worth asking someone else), but i suspect that for "nice" shaped functions, like you seem to be using, newton's method would be fairly quick.

you want to find x such that y = a f(x) + (1-a) g(x).  in other words, when 0 = a f(x) + (1-a) g(x) - y.

so let's define r(x) = a f(x) + (1-a) g(x) - y and find the "zero" of that.  start with a guess in the middle, x_0 = 0.5.  calculate x_1 = x_0 - r(x_0) / r'(x_0).  repeat.  if you are lucky this will rapidly converge (if not, you might consider defining the functions relative to y=x, which you already seem to be doing, and trying it again).

see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)

Answer (score 1):

This problem can't be solved algebraically, in general.

Consider for instance

`y = 2e^x` (inverse `x = log 0.5y`)

and

`y = 2x` (inverse `x = 0.5y`).

Blending these together with weight 0.5 gives `y = e^x+x`, and it is well-known that it is not possible to solve for `x` here using only elementary functions, even though the inverse of each piece was easy to find.

You will want to use a numerical method to approximate the inverse, as discussed by andrew above.